# How to determine whether a piecewise function has a derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Could someone show me a worked example of showing whether a piecewise function is differentiable at some $x=a$?

I can show that it is continuous at $a$, as the limit as $x\to a$ (from both sides) equals the value of the function at that point.

The problem I have is what I do next. Is there any other method than taking the limit as $h\to 0$ of $( f(a+h) - f(a) )/ h$, that is simpler/easier? Also, if I use the $h\to 0$ method.... well what does $f(a+h)$ mean for a piecewise function? What is its value?

Comment: To find examples, look at the Related column in the sidebar on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Use the very well-known property: a limit exists if the left-hand and right-hand limits exist and are equal.

---

**Example:**

$$f(x):=\begin{cases}x\le0\to-x^2,\\x\ge0\to x^2.\end{cases}$$

Now

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}h=\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{-h^2}h=0,$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}h=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{h^2}h=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

It's often just a matter of differentiating the two parts of the function and seeing whether their derivatives match up at the critical point. For example, suppose we have

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}3x^2-2 & \text{if $x\le 2$}\\
 x^3+2 & \text{if $x>2$}\end{cases}$$

You can check that the functions $3x^2-2$ and $x^3+2$ have the same value ($10$) and the same derivative ($12$) at $x=2$; so the function $f$ is differentiable everywhere.

Comment: Note that one-sided derivatives are enough. E.g. $\begin{cases}-|x|& \text{if $x\le0$}\\
 |x| & \text{if $x>0$}\end{cases}$

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Your example is too simple! $f(x)=x$ for all $x$...

Comment: I know, but no piece is differentiable at $x=0$. I think you missed that.